# SQL Server gives syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I have following SQL for Microsoft SQL Server

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblA
WHERE CREATION_DATE BETWEEN DATE'2015-09-12' AND DATE'2015-09-15'
```

But this throws a syntax error:

> Error: Incorrect syntax near '2015-09-12'. SQLState:  S0001 ErrorCode:
>   102

What is wrong? I want to use ANSI literal code.

Comment: is the column creation_date defined as a date datatype? could you add the design of the table please? possibly you should cast.

Comment: SQL server does not support ANSI Date literals, you would need to cast a string literal to DATE - `CAST('2015-09-12' AS DATE)`. Also, [take care when using `BETWEEN` with dates](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @GarethD, but you can use ODBC literals like {d'2015-09-12'} and {ts'2015-09-15 23:59:59'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how you cast in MS SQL Server. Instead, you should try the `cast` syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tblA
WHERE  creation_date BETWEEN CAST('2015-09-12' AS DATE) AND 
                             CAST('2015-09-15' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use this query, without adding date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblA
WHERE CREATION_DATE BETWEEN '2015-09-12' AND '2015-09-15'
```

Comment: What if you use Oracle for the same query? I get the literal error with this.

Comment: @Guil I answered with respect to SQL only as the question was tagged SQL, not Oracle.

Comment: Well, I ask you now, what about Oracle?

Comment: Try this: 
SELECT * 
FROM tblA
WHERE CREATION_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-09-12','YYYY-MON-DD')
      AND TO_DATE('2015-09-15','YYYY-MON-DD')

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tblA
WHERE  CREATION_DATE BETWEEN CAST('2015-09-12' AS DATE) 
                         AND CAST('2015-09-15' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Date literals are tricky... besides the problem with conversion (often depending on your system's culture) you must think of the day's end if you use between!

Here you find a system independent way to literally write dates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (look at "ODBC)

So you could write

```
BETWEEN {d'2015-09-12'} AND {ts'2015-09-12 23:59:59'}
```